# Return dataframe in dictionary format

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
 endpoint_id   key      value     name  id  category_id  category_name
0    60       host     xx.xx.xx   SP    16       5         Database
1    60       username  dbc       SP    16       5         Database
2    60       password  dbc       SP    16       5         Database
3    61       username  abcd      SP_S3 17       6         Storage
4    61       password  wxyz      SP_S3 17       6         Storage
```

I need to return this dataframe in json format.

I have tried with `to_dict('orient = records)` and the output I got was:

```
[
    {
      "endpoint_id": 60,
      "key": "host",
      "value": "10.10.132.163",
      "endpoint_name": "SP_Teradata",
      "id": 16,
      "category_id": 5,
      "category_name": "Database"
    },
    {
      "endpoint_id": 60,
      "key": "username",
      "value": "dbc",
      "name": "SP_Teradata",
      "id": 16,
      "category_id": 5,
      "category_name": "Database"
    },
```

I need the format to be grouped by the endpoint_id, i.e. in the following format :

```
 [ {
  "endpoint_id": 60,
  "endpoint_name": "SP",
  "id": 16,
  "category_id": 5,
  "category_name": "Database",
  "details":[
   "key"  : "host",
   "value":"xx.xx.xx",
   "key"  :"username",
   "value":"dbc",
   "key"  :"password",
   "value":"dbc"
 ]
},
 {
  "endpoint_id": 61,
  "name": "SP_S3",
  "id": 17,
  "category_id": 6,
  "category_name": "Storage",
  "details":[
   "key": "username",
   "value":"abcd",
   "key"  :"password",
   "value":"wxyz"
 ]
}
]
```

How to achieve this syntax wise?

Comment: What was wrong with `to_dict` and `orient=records`? What other options for `orient` are there? What happened when you tried them?

Comment: Try :
df.to_json(orient='records')

Comment: Are you sure that such final structure `[
   "key"  : "host",
   "value":"xx.xx.xx",
   "key"  :"username",
   "value":"dbc",
   "key"  :"password",
   "value":"dbc"
 ]` is convenient ?

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary cannot have more than one same key. Try this:

```
dfx=df.groupby('endpoint_id').agg({'key':list,'value':list,'name':'first','id':'first','category_id':'first','category_name':'first'})
dfx['details']=dfx.apply(lambda x: [dict(zip(x['key'], x['value']))],axis=1)
'''
|   endpoint_id | key                              | value                      | name   |   id |   category_id | category_name   | details                                                    |
|--------------:|:---------------------------------|:---------------------------|:-------|-----:|--------------:|:----------------|:-----------------------------------------------------------|
|            60 | ['host', 'username', 'password'] | ['xx.xx.xx', 'dbc', 'dbc'] | SP     |   16 |             5 | Database        | {'host': 'xx.xx.xx', 'username': 'dbc', 'password': 'dbc'} |
|            61 | ['username', 'password']         | ['abcd', 'wxyz']           | SP_S3  |   17 |             6 | Storage         | {'username': 'abcd', 'password': 'wxyz'}                   |
'''
dfx=dfx.reset_index()
final_dict=dfx.drop(['key','value'],axis=1).to_dict('records')
```

**Output**:

```
[
    {
        "endpoint_id":60,
        "name":"SP",
        "id":16,
        "category_id":5,
        "category_name":"Database",
        "details":[
            {
                "host":"xx.xx.xx",
                "username":"dbc",
                "password":"dbc"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "endpoint_id":61,
        "name":"SP_S3",
        "id":17,
        "category_id":6,
        "category_name":"Storage",
        "details":[
            {
                "username":"abcd",
                "password":"wxyz"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```